# Multiple summations in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to make a system to calculate the Multivariate Hypergeometric Distribution in card games. The equation appear like this:

[image: Click to see image]

Is it possible to use Google Sheets to solve this, given that F, E and P are variables which will be solved through multiple steps (essentially finding P first, then E and finally F) ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question belongs on https://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I saw other Google Sheet questions in here, so I assumed it was the place to post it.. Where can I see which questio belongs where?

Answer (score 1):

There's a built in funtion for this called [HYPGEOMDIST](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094004?hl=en).

You can look up [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k5lxj5-N6ug&ab_channel=PhilJarina) too if you don't trust the formula

Comment: Unfortunately I'm unable to achieve the result I want through the normal Hypergeometric Distribution which is why I'm using the Multivariate Hypergeometric Distribution